# Unable to execute a mysql query

Tags: mysql

i am unable to execute one query.
I want to get result from 2 tables tbl_order_detail, and tbl_order_lead_send_detail
where tbl_order_detail has the dealer_id, so I want to convert that dealer_id to dealer_name (dealer_name is mentioned in table tbl_order_lead_send_detail)

```
SELECT tbl_order_detail.*, tbl_order_lead_send_detail.dealer_name 
where tbl_order_detail.order_status='Active'
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    select tbl_order_detail.*, tbl_order_lead_send_detail.dealer_name 
    from tbl_order_detail, tbl_order_lead_send_detail
    where tbl_order_detail.order_status='Active'
```

missing from clause

but you will also need to join these two table together? what links them?

where tbl1.field1=tbl2.field5

for example

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the from clause from the query.

The query without joining condition will create a cartesian product of both of table and you will get the number of rows in result = (No of row in Table1 * No of row in table2) with each possible combination.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT od.*, olsd.dealer_name from tbl_order_detail od join
>   tbl_order_lead_send_detail olsd ON od.dealer_id=olsd.dealer_id where
>   od.order_status='Active'

First thing there is error in query, you have not define any table and

Second I have assumed relation between these table by dealer_id ie both have dealer_id common... Is this what u want?

If you dont have much knowledge about the join then see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) or  [this](http://mysqljoin.com/)